# Passing a variable to a nested function is being cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pass a *delete id* to a bootstrap modal that on confirm calls the delete element function with that id. Everything works the first time, but for some reason when I try the second, third, etc. it always tries passing in the location id of the element that was originally triggered, which may not exist anymore.

If I move the `removeElement(deleteID)` function call before the bootstrap modal is invoked everything works fine every time – but then there's no user confirmation – it's only when attempting to add this delete function call within the bootstrap modal does the ID appear to get stored. How can I make sure that a new ID is accessible within bootstrap modal func every time?

```
document.addEventListener("click", removeLocationListener);
function removeLocationListener(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    if (element.tagName == 'A' && element.classList.contains("delete-location")) {
        var deleteID = element.getAttribute("data-location-id")
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#removeLocation').modal('show')
        $("#removeLocation").on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
            removeElement(deleteID)
            $('#removeLocation').modal('hide')
        });

    }
}
function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Your `$("#removeLocation").on("click" ...` keeps adding event listeners, so when you click a second delete link, the `removeElement` function runs twice.

Answer (score 0):

As described by @Chris G the reason is clear.

Now the question is how to solve that problem.

The first and fast mode is to change this line:

```
$("#removeLocation").on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
```

to:

```
$("#removeLocation").one("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
```

For more reading see [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Another way can be based on a data attribute.
Before showing the modal you may set a **deleteID** data attribute to the removeLocation and after you can read it:

```
document.addEventListener("click", removeLocationListener);
function removeLocationListener(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    if (element.tagName == 'A' && element.classList.contains("delete-location")) {
        var deleteID = element.getAttribute("data-location-id")
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#removeLocation").data('deleteID', deleteID); // save deleteID
        $('#removeLocation').modal('show');
    }
}
$("#removeLocation").on("click", ".btn-danger", function (e) {
    var deleteID = $("#removeLocation").data('deleteID');  // read deleteID
    removeElement(deleteID)
    $('#removeLocation').modal('hide')
});
function removeElement(elementId) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's a mix of Vanilla JS and jQuery I cleaned up the code a bit:

```js
var $nodeToDelete = null;

$("#removeLocation").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
  if ($nodeToDelete) $nodeToDelete.remove();
  $nodeToDelete = null;
  $('#removeLocation').modal('hide');
});

$(document).on("click", "a.delete-location", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("location-id");
  $nodeToDelete = $("#" + id);
  $('#removeLocation .modal-title span').text(id);
  $('#removeLocation').modal('show');
});
```

```css
a.delete-location {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="removeLocation" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Remove Location <span></span>?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<p id="123">Location 123 <a class="delete-location" href="#" data-location-id="123">X</a></p>
<p id="456">Location 456 <a class="delete-location" href="#" data-location-id="456">X</a></p>
```

I mostly merged the delete click handler and `removeLocation`, and used jQuery throughout.